# Factoring a matrix out of linear matrix equation

Tags: matrices, inverse, factoring

I'm having a bit of trouble following a solution in a textbook, one step in particular.

I have the equation $(Z + tV)^{-1}$ where $Z$, $V$ are matrices and $t$ is a scalar. $Z$ is positive definite, and $V$ is symmetric. The next step implies that

$$
    (Z + tV)^{-1} = Z^{-1}(I + tZ^{-1/2}VZ^{-1/2})^{-1}
$$

Now I can understand factoring out $Z$ first, i.e. $(Z + tV) = Z(I + tZ^{-1/2}VZ^{-1/2})$, but then I thought $(AB)^{-1} = B^{-1}A^{-1}$, i.e. the order switches (and given that both $A$ and $B$ are invertible). Maybe then $Z$ is factored out on the right first, then that property is applied?

Thanks for any help, I'm clearly not too hot on linear algebra.

Comment: Please use Latex!

Comment: I don't understand how could you factor out $Z$ like this. Notice that $Z+tV=Z^{1/2}(I+tZ^{-1/2}VZ^{-1/2})Z^{1/2}$, so $(Z+tV)^{-1}=Z^{-1/2}(I+tZ^{-1/2}VZ^{-1/2})^{-1}Z^{-1/2}$ or $Z+tV=Z(I+tZ^{-1}V)$ so $(Z+tV)^{-1}=(I+tZ^{-1}V)^{-1}Z^{-1}$.